# iPhone and iPad application compatibility

Tags: asp.net, ipad, mobile-safari, mobile-website, iphone

What should I do  an existing asp.net based web site  for running under iphone and ipad environment without problem ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

good question (+1 voted)! there are lots of resources on this but talking from experience the main things I'd cater for are:

- ensure there's no vital flash objects
  on the page as it isn't supported by
  many mobile browsers (yet?)
- appropriate screen size (using
  viewport meta tag)
- keeping in mind that there's no mouse
  cursors, meaning no
  hover/double-clicks are available any
  mouse dragging gestures are different
  on touch devices
- remember all pop-ups are open in new
  tabs and won't be seen at the same
  time as the main window, use
  javascript modal divs as alternative
- test all your javascript and css to
  ensure everything looks and works the
  same (Safari requires -webkit- prefix
  for the newest CSS properties)
- create a Home screen icon for your
  website (a nice thing to have)

most of these things are covered [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#codinghowtos/Mobile/UserExperience/_index.html)

take a look at [Safari Dev Center](http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/safari/index.action) for tutorials/videos/coding how to's etc.

Comment: @Bad Display Name-First of all,thanks for your reply.But,I used a lot of flash in my web site.According to the research,iPhone doesn't  support flash applications.What should I do here?

Comment: uh oh, sorry I didn't even think of that as we never had FLASH objects in our sites. You're in trouble there, I'm afraid (see my 1st bullet point I just added)

Comment: so, what are you going to do about the flash? youtube videos are supported but if you have flash animation could they be replaced by the modern css/javascript stuff? It is doable [link]http://webdesignerwall.com/trends/47-amazing-css3-animation-demos

Comment: I want to ask a question.is it to fill a healthy those forms in my web site any user which access to my asp.net based web site with iPhone or iPad?

Comment: sorry :) I withdraw the question.thanks for your all answers.